# IE9 does not seem to recognise $.ajax's 'complete' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using ajax to allow the user to filter content that appears in a target div (`var target`).

While the content loads, I show a div containing a loader image `('#loader')`.

However, when the ajax call is done, IE doesn't re-hide the loader as other browsers do.

It also indentifies the the setTimeout() call (in the ajax callback) as an 'invalid argument'.

If I didn't find this so baffling I wouldn't ask here. Thanks!

CODE:

```
function run_ajax() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'artworks_ajax',
    beforeSend: function(){
        target.empty();
        $('#loader').fadeIn();
    },  
    complete: function() {
        $('#loader').fadeOut('fast')
    },  
    data: {
      'select' : 'artworks',
      'artwork-filter': JSON.stringify(filter)
    },  
    success: function(data) {
      target.hide();
      target.html(data);
      fireMasonry();
      reloadMasonry();  // masonry needs reminding how big its div is
      setTimeout(
        fadeUp()
      , 1000); // pause necessary to give masonry time to fix itself in place
      }   
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Your setTimeout invokes fadeUp() then schedules its return value; did you intend function(){fadeUp()} ?

Comment: @AlexK: No need for that, you only need to do `setTimeout(fadeUp, 1000)`

Comment: fadeUp was my waterloo, @josh.trow is right, i think. sorry for such a dumb q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a semicolon missing at the end here:

```
$('#loader').fadeOut('fast')
```

Also, the first argument to `setTimeout` should be a function, while here you are *calling* the function and using its return value. Assuming that `fadeUp` is a free function, it should be like this:

```
setTimeout(fadeUp, 1000);
```

Comment: you are very kind - thank you. sorry, i'm being a bit dim today

Comment: I thought semi colon in javscripts is negligible

Comment: @YouQi: Why on earth did you think that? Also: doing `setTimeout("fadeUp()", 1000)` will work, but many people (including myself) find this ugly and messy. And there is no benefit.

Comment: and again, I thought the corrrect way of calling setTimeout should be setTimeout("fadeUp()", 1000);

Comment: for semicolon, the fact is it works that way. how you not expecting me to think like that? addon: ohyea~ I learnt something new today regarding the alternative setTimeout approach. thanks! :)

Comment: @Jon - Semicolons are not required in JavaScript in most cases, and not in this case. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @nnnnnn: That is true, but the blanket statement "semicolons are not required" is not. For this specific answer, I simply listed all "issues" I found when scanning the code by eye, and I have long trained myself to put semicolons *everywhere* (like e.g. braces in C-style one-line `if` statements).

Comment: Blanket statements are always wrong. (Ha!) Seriously though, I put a semicolon at the end of every statement too, but I recognise the cases when they're not required so I wouldn't report those cases as errors in somebody else's code. Having said that, it does annoy me when people leave them out randomly - better to make the decision either to always use 'em (as we both do) or use them only when necessary. I like consistency.

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason there is still an issue, you can move complete to be after the ajax call like so: `$.ajax({ajax_stuff_goes_here}).complete(function() {$('#loader').fadeOut('fast');});`

Comment: thanks, that's very interesting, i may use that in future. Jon's answer was enough, tho